Error running a zero-inflated beta-binomial model with ZIBR
I'm trying to run a zero-inflated beta binomial model using the package ZIBR on some behavioral data. My data is [0,1) and I'm interested in if there are species differences in the proportion of time individuals spent in a white area of a tank across three trials.
A subsample of my data is provided below for reference:
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      fishID = c(
        "fish1","fish1","fish1", "fish105","fish105","fish105","fish106", "fish106","fish106","fish12","fish12",
        "fish12","fish16","fish16","fish16", "fish17","fish17","fish17","fish18","fish18","fish18"
      ),
      species = c(
        "melasma","melasma","melasma","prasites","prasites","prasites","prasites","prasites","prasites","teresae",
        "teresae","teresae","melasma","melasma","melasma","teresae","teresae","teresae","teresae","teresae",
        "teresae"
      ),
      whiteprop = c(
        0.482938889,0,0,0,0.028264444,0,0.101271111,0.113006667,0.031126667,0.274194444,0.521831111,0.369093333,
        0.121565556,0.230355556,0,0,0,0,0.020068889,0,0
      ),
      time = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,
               1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-21L),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame")
  )


zibr_fit <- zibr(
  logistic_cov = df$species, beta_cov = df$species, Y = df$whiteprop,
  subject_ind = df$fishID, time_ind = df$time
)

However, I get the following error:

Error in if (nrow(logistic_cov) != nrow(Y) || nrow(beta_cov) != nrow(Y)) { :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I have already confirmed that there are no missing values in my data frame and each column is the same length. I've also run each component within the code above with success.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Looks like the covariate and y inputs need to be matrices.
Original Data
library(ZIBR)
library(dplyr)
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      fishID = c(
        "fish1","fish1","fish1", "fish105","fish105","fish105","fish106", "fish106","fish106","fish12","fish12",
        "fish12","fish16","fish16","fish16", "fish17","fish17","fish17","fish18","fish18","fish18"
      ),
      species = c(
        "melasma","melasma","melasma","prasites","prasites","prasites","prasites","prasites","prasites","teresae",
        "teresae","teresae","melasma","melasma","melasma","teresae","teresae","teresae","teresae","teresae",
        "teresae"
      ),
      whiteprop = c(
        0.482938889,0,0,0,0.028264444,0,0.101271111,0.113006667,0.031126667,0.274194444,0.521831111,0.369093333,
        0.121565556,0.230355556,0,0,0,0,0.020068889,0,0
      ),
      time = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,
               1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-21L),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame")
  )


Data to Matrices
You could use model.matrix() or in this case since there is only a single categorical variable, I used fastDummies::dummy_cols().  In any event, the covariate inputs need to be design matrices not data.
lc <- df %>% 
  select(species) %>% 
  fastDummies::dummy_cols("species", 
                          remove_first_dummy = TRUE, 
                          remove_selected_columns = TRUE) %>% 
  as.matrix()

Run model
zibr_fit <- zibr(
  logistic_cov = lc, 
  beta_cov = lc, 
  Y = matrix(df$whiteprop, ncol=1), 
  subject_ind = df$fishID, 
  time_ind = df$time
)
zibr_fit$logistic_est_table
#>                       Estimate    Pvalue
#> intersept        -2.506062e-08 0.9999987
#> species_prasites  9.027897e-01 0.6117194
#> species_teresae  -2.855026e-01 0.8588015

Created on 2024-11-25 with reprex v2.1.0

I think you need to make your categorical predictors into matrices of indicator/dummy variables, i.e. something like this:
with(df, 
    zibr(logistic_cov = model.matrix(~species), 
         beta_cov = model.matrix(~species), 
         Y = whiteprop, subject_ind = fishID, time_ind = time))

(using with() is just cosmetic, to avoid rewriting df$ too many times)
For what it's worth, this is Beta regression, not beta-binomial regression ...
